# Recursion not getting past first level

Tags: javascript, recursion, mongoose

I'm having trouble with recursion in JS and I'm not sure why my code won't terminate. I have a mongoose schema that goes through a list of courts, and each court has users (which I then use to search for signatures using another schema). I want to return an object with all the users from the level inputted to the lowest level. Here's my code:

```
    async function recurCourtUsers(username) {
        ContactSchema.findOne({'users': {$elemMatch: {userName: username}}}).lean().then(async function(courts) {
          let level = courts.level;
          let courtName = courts.orgName.substring(0,2);
          let result = await searchModule.findCourt(courtName, level); // returns an object

          if (level === 4) {
            console.log('now at lvl4')
            console.log(result); 

          } else {
            level++
            var temp = await searchModule.findCourt(courtName, level);
            console.log(temp); 
            result.courts.concat(temp.courts);
            result.collections.concat(temp.collections);
            recurCourtUsers(courts.users[0].userName);
          }          
        });
      }
      recurCourtUsers(req.body.username);
```

I don't think there's anything incorrect in searchModule.findCourt() as it just finds the court and gets the signatures, returning an object that looks like

```
{
  courts: [{courtObjects}] //array of court Objects
  collection: [] //array of users that have signatures
}

// a courtObject looks like this:

{
   _id: objectId,
   orgName: "NY court"
   level: 3 // there are up to 4 levels, 1 being the "highest" or start
   users: [{userName: "15z", displayName: "court2"}]
}
```

My problem is that if I start at level 2, this function keeps printing out all level 3 courts. I'd like to print all courts starting from level 2 (which is stored in the result variable), then go to level 3, lastly going to level 4. But this function just gets stuck at the next level and never seems to increase the level variable after one recursion. Also, should I return anything (like the result variable)? Should I use an accumulator instead?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: await recurCourtUsers(courts.users[0].userName);
as it returns a promise

Comment: Just added await, but it still goes on forever. It prints out the correct courts at the next level, but then keeps doing that.

Comment: not sure but can you try changing var temp  to let temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain my theory, let me know if it makes sense:

Here, I've commented out every line that doesn't affect the recursion call:

```js
async function recurCourtUsers(username) {
    ContactSchema.findOne({'users': {$elemMatch: {userName: username}}}).lean().then(async function(courts) {
      let level = courts.level;
      // let courtName = courts.orgName.substring(0,2);
      // let result = await searchModule.findCourt(courtName, level); // returns an object

      if (level === 4) {
        console.log('now at lvl4')
        console.log(result); 

      } else {
        // level++
        // var temp = await searchModule.findCourt(courtName, level);
        // console.log(temp); 
        // result.courts.concat(temp.courts);
        // result.collections.concat(temp.collections);
        recurCourtUsers(courts.users[0].userName);
      }          
    });
}
recurCourtUsers(req.body.username);
```

Let me remove them for clarity:

```js
async function recurCourtUsers(username) {
    ContactSchema.findOne({'users': {$elemMatch: {userName: username}}}).lean().then(async function(courts) {
      let level = courts.level;

      if (level === 4) {
        console.log('now at lvl4')
        console.log(result); 
      } else {
        recurCourtUsers(courts.users[0].userName);
      }          
    });
}
recurCourtUsers(req.body.username);
```

If you pay attention to that, you seem to be using the first user from the court you found using the user's username. Which leads me to think, that when you call the method again: `courts.users[0].userName === req.body.username`.

That is probably what keeps you in an infinite loop.